# Convergence of harmonic power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Find the interval of convergence for the series,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot x^n$$

I have no clue where to even being assessing this infinite series, however I can see that the harmonic series comes into play somehow. I am wondering if it's possible to rewrite the series as a nested, represented as the following,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot x^n\right)$$

Would this be productive at all? I believe that it is necessary to use squeeze theorem to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = |x|$, and it should also be shown that $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ if $|x|\geq1$. However, I have no clue to to approach either of these problems. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the power series of $-\log(1-x)/(1-x)$ about $x=0$? Btw, shouldn't you use two different summation indices in the nested sum? Why does the inner sum extends to infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You correctly surmise that can use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) to obtain the answer:
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|&=\left|\frac{\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i}\right)x^{n+1}}{\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\right)x^n}\right|\\
&=|x|\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}}\right)\ .
\end{align}
What's the limit of this expression as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I now see that the partial sum of the series n+1 could be broken down into 1/n + 1/n+1, thanks for helping me see that! The conclusion would then be that |x| < 1 for the series to converge. Evaluating |x| = 1; at x = 1, the series diverges as the harmonic series diverges. At x = -1, the series also diverges because the alternating harmonic series converges to ln(2). Since this gives the infinite series of ln(2), the entire series diverges. I hope my logic is right, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Your reasoning for the cases $\ |x|<1\ $ and $\ x=1\ $ is correct.  For $\ x=-1\ $, however, the divergence of the series can be concluded from the fact that $\ a_n=(-1)^n\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\ $ diverges, since this sequence must converge to zero for its sequence of successive sums to converge. The sequence alternates between positive and negative values of increasingly large magnitudes, so its divergence has nothing to do with the convergence of the alternating harmonic series to $\ \ln2\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ be the $n^{th}$ harmonic number. There is the famous Cauchy-Hadamard formula for the radius of convergence of a given power series, namely
\begin{align}
R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|H_n|^{1/n}}
\end{align}
In our case, note that the Harmonic numbers are roughly logarithmic, i.e once we get past the first few terms, we can find $c,C>0$ such that for all large enough $n$, $c\log n\leq H_n\leq C\log n$. This is essentially because $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sim\int_1^n\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\log n$. So, by using the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(c\log n)^{1/n}=1$ (since $c>0$) and likewise with $C\log n$, we see that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}H_n^{1/n}=1$. Hence, $R=1$.